# highcharts - custom legend width

Tags: highcharts

I have a simple line chart with a legend aligned to the right. Legend width is set based on the legend item content, if the content doesn't exceed 25% of the width of the chart, it stays as it is. But if it exceeds - 25% is applied. The code for this is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sabira/zfqLyax7/5/).
The problem is that I am facing a situation when legend text has long string without white spaces in between - like `PricewaterhouseCooper`, the text gets cutoff - which is expected result based on the code. However I wanted to eliminate this scenario and let it exceed 25% if there is a string which width is wider than 25%. Do you have suggestion how better approach this problem?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I think that rendering the legends as outstanding HTML elements and styled them could be the best approach in your case - just like is suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is using custom legend HTML to use custom styling for it. Highchart can be very strong at custom style for your chart.

I created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tmbLo1yq/) for an example of it.

In my example, I used "**min-width**" and "max-width" based on percent of your container width. Also different "font-family" can cause a different results.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<style>@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';

 #container {
      min-width: 300px;
      max-width: 500px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 1em auto;
 }
</style>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
    styledMode: true,
    events: {
    load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      legend = chart.legend,
      legendMaxWidth =
        Highcharts.relativeLength(legend.options.maxWidth, 1) * chart.chartWidth;

        /*if (legend.legendWidth > legendMaxWidth) {
          legend.update({
            width: legend.options.maxWidth
          });
        }*/
      }
      }
    },
    legend: {
    align: 'right',
    layout: 'proximate',
    maxWidth: '25%',
    width: '25%',
    /* use custom html */
    useHTML: true,
    labelFormatter: function () {
        return '<span title="' + this.name + '" style="max-width:110px;min-width:75px;display:block;word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal;letter-spacing: 0.5px;">' + this.name + '</span>';
    }
  },
  series: [{
  name: 'PricewaterhouseCoopers',
  data: [1, 4, 3, 5],
},{
  name: 'Pricewaterhouse Coopers copy',
  data: [2, 1, 0, 3],
},
{
  name: 'Deloitteverylongtexthere',
  data: [3, 5, 3, 1],
}
]
});

</script>
```